# Under what condition is the complement of a subring closed under multiplication?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

For the converse there is a weaker statement that goes as follows:

> let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and $S$ a subring of $A$. If $A-S$ is closed under multiplication, then $S$ is integrally closed.

Under which condition is the converse true?

I am asking to request other results regarding the behavior of the complement of a subring. Thank you.

Comment: The complement is never a subring because it doesn't contain zero. Your question seems to be a bit more vague than the title however, so perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: @MattSamuel Corrected. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: It's also never closed under addition because if it contains some element $x$, it also contains $-x$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Can we remove the assumption that the complement contains additive inverse to avoid this?

Comment: That's not an assumption. The complement of a subring always contains additive inverses. This is because if a subring contains $x$, then it also contains $-x$.

Comment: @WilliamSun It is not an *assumption* that the complement contains the additive inverse, it is a provable fact: for any $a\in A\setminus S$, if $-a\in S$, then $-(-a)=a\in S$, a contradiction.  You'd have to stop believing $S$ is closed under addition if you want to sidestep this problem.

Comment: @rschwieb You are absolutely right. My apologies.